# javascript debug who is blocking form submit

Tags: javascript

I have a lot `JS` files in legacy project. Some `JS` code is blocking form submit, how I can find what `JS` events is listening form submit ?

Comment: You can use the developer tools from the browser to see this. Bring it up by ctrl + shift + C

Comment: Or just F12 key (this also opens the developer tools in the browsers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome actually has a great tool that is able to do this. Right-click on the submit button and open dev tools. Then go to event listeners in the sub tab from there you should be able to see the submit action. You can expand the action and view the source.

[image]

Comment: Uh, nice 1, i didnt know that!

Answer (score 1):

the comments are a good start, additionally search through all files for any reference to the forms name or id and if thats not enout for any code looping through all forms.

depending on the techniques used, e.g. jquery you might need to change your search like

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")

$("form")

$("#ID_OF_FORM).submit
```

and so on... i guess best chances by using the ID of the form

Answer (score 1):

You can also add event listener in Console Tab.
More in article below.

[How to debug Front-end: Console](https://blog.pragmatists.com/how-to-debug-front-end-console-3456e4ee5504)